# how to start and stop application in apache-tomcat manually if there are more than one application in webapps directory of tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Actually i have two application in webapps directory of tomcat

```
  webapps/hello_web1 and
  webapps/hello_web2
```

I want to start and stop these to apps separably and by using command line (or any other way except using tomcat manager gui so that i can implement start and stop function manually in my program).

Please suggest me if it is possible, and if it is not possible in tomcat than suggest me web server in which it is possible.

Comment: You can call tomcat manager using its url from command line using `wget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of deploying web applications in Apache Tomcat. One is the XML deployment descriptor file in the directory `<TOMCATDIR>/conf/Catalina/localhost`.

The content of such a file is a `<Context...></Context>` configuration that may look like this (eg. `webapp1.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context displayName="webapp1"
         override="true"
         path="/webapp1"
         docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/webapp1">

         ... some context configuration ...

</Context>
```

If Tomcat finds a XML file in this directory, it will try to deploy the context defined in that file. If you remove that file from this directory, Tomcat will undeploy the web application context.

All of that can be done by command line or shell script.

Regarding to your question: You may put two context files in this directory. One for each of your web apps. To deploy one just move the file in and to undeploy one just move it out of the directory.

```bash
# deployment
&> cd "<TOMCATPATH>/conf/Catalina/"
&> mv webapp1.xml localhost/
  
# undeploy
&> cd "<TOMCATPATH>/conf/Catalina/localhost"
&> mv webapp1.xml ../
```

For more detailed information about the `<Context...></Context>` element refer to: [The Context Container Doc Page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 4):

Best way is using `CURL` targetting your desired command from Tomcat /manager

```
curl --user user:pass http://localhost:8080/manager/text/<your command>?path=/<your web appl>
```

here you can find list of commands 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

in your case

> Start Application
>   `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/start?path=/yourWebAppl`
>
> Stop Application
>   `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/stop?path=/yourWebAppl`
>
> Restart Application
>   `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/yourWebAppl`